# How about SwiftUI's large image handling, performance & efficiency

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

How does SwiftUi handle large images and which way of adding them is preferred? Are there some suggestions on how images should be shrinked in pixel size or file size? I did my research but could not find useful information on it.

In my case, I'm displaying four graphics in my SwiftUI view with image dimensions e.g. 1284px × 1783px and a file size on disk of 2.3 MB. Is this bad? I need them to have very good quality in order to be sharp and adjust to frame sizes on iPhone, iPad, ... They are presented with at least 50% of screen width and height.

Thanks a lot for your explanation(s). This does not seem to be documented well anywhere, to me.